# Angular 7 directive with keydown event of input type "number" not prevent on Android phone for special character dot and minus

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

In angular 7 directive, keydown event is not prevent the key in android device for special character like dot and minus. Please help to provide the solution. I have used below code

```
    import { Directive, OnInit, ElementRef, HostListener } from "@angular/core";
    
    @Directive({
            selector:'[numberOnly]'
    })
    export class AllowNumberDirective {
    
        regexStr = '^[0-9]+$'
        constructor(private el: ElementRef){        
            console.log("constructor triggered", el);
        }
    
        @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
        onKeyDown(event){        
            return new RegExp(this.regexStr).test(event.key);        
        }
     }
```

Used HTML tag

```html
<input numberOnly style="width: 200px; height: 25px;" type="number" />
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is working absolutely fine.

Please take a look at this stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tojuni?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnumbersonly.directive.ts

All you need to do is add the directive in the declarations part in the module in which you are using this component.

Comment: thank Srikar.. Its working fine in IOS and web. its not working in all Android device

Answer (score 0):

Hi For android only users, you can use something like this:

This will test only for android users and in the else condition you can have your regular code for rest of the Operating Systems.

```
const opera = 'opera';
const userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window[opera];
if (/android/i.test(userAgent) && event.target && event.target.value) {
  const regexStr = '^[0-9]+$';
  return new RegExp(regexStr).test(event.key)
}
```